# Brompton pump mount?

Tags: frames, pump, brompton

I have recently acquired a Brompton, which came with this zefal pump, which doesn't clip onto the frame:

[image]

The rear frame on my Brompton doesn't appear to have the cage-like mounts that new models have. The mountings that it does have are shown below. Are these intended for a pump, and if so, is there a specific pump that attached so these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have mounts on my road bike for a pump either.  As an alternative, I use a couple of velcro cable ties to hold the pump in place and stop rattles.  It hasn't fallen off yet, and also hasn't fouled the moving parts.

Comment: Actually - scratch my previous comment.  The pump has eroded the frame paint where it touched.  This might work if you stored the pump in a cloth sock or wrapping.  In the end I replaced it with a mini pump and a holder that goes under the water bottle cage, then velcro strapped that on.  No paint damage yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a Mk2 Brompton which uses a slightly shorter pump. I think your pump might be a Mk2 also. Does it physically fit within the frame? (the handle goes towards the axle).

The bit you are missing is the adapter bolt for holding the Zefal pump. This goes into the seatpost-end pump bracket and slots into the hole on the nozzle end of your pump. You could maybe improvise something with parts from a hardware store.

You could also try to get hold of a Bluemels pump, which is what the mounts were originally designed for, although these are now incredibly rare.

Much more info about Brompton pumps can be found in [this Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/638481376239887/permalink/673823046039053/).

Answer (score 2):

I have a Brompton of around that vintage (1998 to be exact) and there is a very good reason why it will not come with the original Bluemels rear-triangle fitting pump and that is that they don't work very well when new and very quickly seize up as a result of all the muck and water thrown over them by the back wheel.

Mine was ditched years ago and replaced by a Topeak pump which I carry around in the front basket. Much nicer, and it works! :-)